# Why is my new function not recreating object when validation error is encountered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm going through my application and making sure that it responds properly to validation issues. In this particular situation, when creating a new delivery order you must use a unique number when creating one. I've found that when I put in a duplicate number the system displays an error.

The error is:

```
undefined method `purchase_request_fundings' for nil:NilClass
```

I understand why this error is occurring but I don't understand how to fix it. The error occurs because after the application finds a validation error, it tries to kick the user back to the delivery order new function with an friendly error message to display to the user however, the @purchase_request object is not being instantiate with any data when it's get back to the new function. I'm thinking it doesn't see the parameters it needs to find and set the object properly and thus the object - @purchase_request - is left as nil.

My Code:

```
Controller

def new                                                                                                                        
  @delivery_order = DeliveryOrder.new(:purchase_request_id => params[:purchase_request])                                       
  @purchase_request = PurchaseRequest.find(@delivery_order.purchase_request_id)                                                
end  

def create                                                                                                                     
  @delivery_order = DeliveryOrder.new(params[:delivery_order])                                                                 

  respond_to do |format|                                                                                                       
    if @delivery_order.save                                                                                                    
      params[:discrete_tasks].each do |key, value|                                                                             
        DeliveryOrderFunding.create(                                                                                           
          :delivery_order_id => @delivery_order.id,                                                                            
          :discrete_task_id => key,                                                                                            
          :amount => value                                                                                                     
        )                                                                                                                      
      end                                                                                                                      

      format.html do                                                                                                           
        flash[:success] = "Delivery Order was succesfully created"                                                            
        redirect_to @delivery_order                                                                                            
      end                                                                                                                      
    else                                                                                                                       
      format.html { render action: "new" }                                                                                     
    end                                                                                                                        
  end                                             
end
```

View includes

```
= hidden_field_tag 'delivery_order[purchase_request_id]', params[:purchase_request]
```

Also tried

```
= hidden_field_tag :purchase_request, params[:purchase_request]
```

Comment: Can you post your `DeliveryOrder` Model? Your code looks like, that there should be a `DeliveryOrder#belongs_to :purchase_request`.
So you might be able to call `@delivery_order.purchase_request`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, your call to `render action: "new"` doesn't call the `new` method in your controller, it only renders the `new` view, using the instance variables that your create method has set. So you need to do something like:

```
def create
   @delivery_order = DeliveryOrder.new(params[:delivery_order]) 

   respond_to do |format|
      if @delivery_order.save
         ...
      else
         format.html do 
            @purchase_request = PurchaseRequest.find(@delivery_order.purchase_request_id)
            render action: "new"
         end
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @danwich...that was easy enough.